# How to get CertPathValidatorResult in checkServerTrusted() of TrustManager?

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, jsse, httpsurlconnection

When the `checkServerTrusted` method of classes implementing `X509TrustManager` is invoked, I need to get ALL validation errors that are associated with a certificate chain including

1. Certificate path validation problems. e.g CA not trusted
2. Certificate fields validation problems. e.g Expired certificate, Invalid extended key usage

The motivation behind this is so that I can present the user with the certificate validation issues before he adds it as an "exception" as Firefox does now. However, right now, as soon as a path validation issue is found, a `CertPathValidatorException` is thrown, but it gives me no information about the validity of the fields in the certificate. How can I implement this?

After some reading, I found the `CertPath` API provides such features, and found that the PKIX implementation is a wrapper around this, but just does not return the `CertPathValidatorResult`. I would like to make maximum use of existing JAVA functionality(without writing my own custom wrapper to the API) while returning all validation issues.

Answer (score 0):

You won't even get to X509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted() if there was a certificate error. You would need to hook the certificate handling at an earlier point, and I don't believe there is one in JSSE.

Comment: I don't believe thats true. From the stacktrace, The checkServerTrusted method is the one that is doing the validation of the certificate. By certificate error, if you mean that the certificate is not formatted right, maybe so, but not otherwise.

Comment: checkServerTrusted() checks whether a valid peer certificate is trusted. If the certificate isn't valid it won't be called. This seems obvious to me.

Comment: Have you actually tried testing your hypothesis like with an expired certificate? I have and AFAIK the validation is done by the PKIXValidator which in invoked by the checkServerTrustedMethod(). See the stacktrace at http://pastebin.com/TE0SwZ6B